# Difference between admin and adminhtml

Tags: admin, adminhtml, scope

I'm searching for info about difference between "***Admin***" and "***Adminhtml***" scope in magento config files (EX: in some *etc/config.xml* node ).

I think the scope of "***Adminhtml***" is the Presentation & Business Logic of the Magento "Admin Panel" but i'm not able to find some scope for "***Admin***"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<admin>` tags allows you to define routes for the backend, the ACL for each module admin section and the theme for the admin.
There are also some fieldsets defined in the `Mage_Catalog` module under this tag but the main things where you can use this tag are the 3 listed above.
**[EDIT]**
And you are right about the `<adminhtml>` tag. It's the equivalent to `<frontend>` for the backend (D'uh!).  It allows you to define layout files, translations, events. The only think different from frontend is that it doesn't allow routes. (use `<admin>` for that).

Comment: Thanks. Did i think right about __adminhtml__ scope ?

Comment: @alesdario. Yes, you got it right. I added some explanations about the `<adminhtml>` for future readers. If you are satisfied with the answer please accept it. Don't leave loose ends.

Comment: @marius : Hello I found `fieldsets` in `Mage_Bundle` module in `etc/config.xml`. Can you explain what it is ?